# How to map primitive type to property of an object implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I would like to have map between `Id` of basically any type but usually something that can be used for db id and all entities implementing `IEntity` interface mapping the `Id` to `Id` property of class implementing the `IEntity` interface.

I have entities each implementing interface `IEntity`.

```cs
interface IEntity
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : IEntity
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have update command for `User` entity.

```cs
public class LinkUserWithCommentsCommand
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List<Guid> CommentIds { get; set; }
}
```

Which I would like to use to map to `User` like so.

```
User MapIWouldLikeToHave(LinkUserWithCommentsCommand command)
{
  return new User
  {
    Id = command.Id,
    Comments = command.CommentIds.Select(id => new Comment { Id = id })
  }
}
```

I have tried using `ForAllMaps` method

```cs
cfg.ForAllMaps(
  (mapConfiguration, map) =>
  {
    if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(mapConfiguration.DestinationType) && mapConfiguration.SourceType == typeof(int))
      map
        .ForMember(nameof(IEntity.Id), options => options.MapFrom(x => (Guid)x));
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work. In docs it says you just need to provide mapping between elements of lists and AutoMapper will be able to map between lists of the elements you provided mapping for.

If you are wondering why I want to have entity with just an id set its for entity framework. Ids in the list are for entities which already exists in db I just need to tell EF to link them to some other entity `_context.Comments.AttachRange(user.Comments);`.

Here is runnable code with info: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/vvmnog